# Find MILL in MSQ data

Tags: database, tcl, storage

I have data that looks like

```
121,736,52,0,5.295,0.000,70.000,3,1.0000,3,1  
122,736,52,0,5.295,0.000,70.000,3,1.0000,3,1  
123,736,52,0,5.295,0.000,70.000,3,1.0000,3,1  
124,736,52,1,5.295,1.000,70.200,3,1.0000,3,1  
124,736,52,OIND,70.200,27.641,-np-  
125,736,52,1,5.295,1.000,72.175,3,1.0000,3,1  
125,736,52,OIND,72.175,308.340,MILL    
129,736,52,1,5.295,1.000,70.525,3,1.0000,3,1  
129,736,52,OIND,70.525,76.211,MILL
```

I need to store all the data that ends with "MILL" or "-np-"
and then need to put it into a new MSQ file

Any suggestions
The language is TCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
set in [open yourfile r]
set out [open newfile w]
while {[gets $in line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {(?:MILL|-np-)$} $line]} {
         puts $out $line
    }
}
close $in
close $out
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Shawn's excellent answer:

```
set in [open yourfile r]
set out [open newfile w]
while {[gets $in line] >= 0} {
    switch -glob -- $line {
        {*MILL} -
        {*-np-} {
             puts $out $line
        }
    }
}
close $in
close $out
```

glob patterns are described in the [`string match` documentation](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35).